# Can we install .deb package on Ubuntu Core OS 16 version

Tags: ubuntu-core

Can we install .deb package on Ubuntu Core OS 16 version
Is it supported and recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: Ubuntu Core systems are incompatible with .deb packages. Ubuntu Core is snap-only.

To install .deb packages, you must use Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server.

Workaround: You CAN install a hypervisor snap onto Ubuntu Core, and then install a deb-compatible OS into the container or Virtual Machine. For example, you can install an LXD snap, then spin up an Ubuntu Server LXD container, then install a deb onto the virtual server inside that container.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply